# Code coverage Threshold does not stop script from running in angular app

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, code-coverage, karma-runner

Im trying to implement a script in my Angular project that i can run when im done with a Feature. I put the script in my project.json.

```
"fin": "ng lint && ng test --watch=false --code-coverage && ng e2e && ng build --prod"
```

I added in my karm.conf.js

```
coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: ["html", "lcovonly"],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
      thresholds: {
        global: {
          statements: 100,
          lines: 100,
          branches: 100,
          functions: 100,
        },
        each: {
          statements: 100,
          lines: 100,
          branches: 100,
          functions: 100,
        },
      },
    },
```

The Goal is it that tslint, unittests with code coverage, e2e tests and production build run with one command, and that the script stops when somthing throws an error. It almost works beside the code coverge part. It does not throw an error when the treshold is not met so that the script keeps on running.

Any idear what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it now. I had to add "coverage-istanbul" to the reporter Array in karma.conf.js.

Answer (score 1):

Do you see a coverage report after running `ng test` like the one shown below?

[image: Coverage report]

I am on Angular 5 and in the `plugins` array I have `require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter')` as well as the `coverageIstanbulReporter` object, I don't have global or each configuration.

This is my `coverageIstanbulReporter` object:

[image: coverageIstanbulReporter]

Check out this [link](https://angular.io/guide/testing-code-coverage) and try to copy the Code Coverage Enforcement section. It can be different than the documentation of `karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter` because I am thinking of the CLI.

[image: Plugins]

Comment: What do you mean with 'plugins array'? For the rest ... yes i see the report and i tried the code from the angular doku aswell. made no diffrents.

Comment: I added a picture with the plugins. I am not sure then.

Comment: Added it.Same result with one Warning on top. Now i get a massage that IstanbulReporter is deprecated since Angular 11

Comment: Thx Alif. While your answer did not get me all the way it put me on the right track.